# Outdated navigation language?

Tags: bug, design, help-center

I'm very new here and was just granted the privilege of meta participation.  That is, while I believe I've found some misleading guidance, the following question may be more a matter of this newbie not knowing his way around.  Grace and mercy, please.

When I reached a Rep of 5, I checked the Recent achievements button up top and clicked on the new "participate in meta" link in that drop-down.  On the page I was directed to, I found the following navigation advice:

> There is a link to meta in the footer of every page.

But I don't actually see Meta listed in the footer of any page except when I'm already on a Meta page.  Am I overlooking something or is the above language left over from a previous interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have encountered the effects of interface updates without matching instruction updates.

The look and feel has been very recently updated, and the text in various messages, and help pages has not been changed to match yet.

To get to Meta from anywhere else on this site (Interpersonal Skills) there are two easy options. 1: In the top-left corner is the text "StackExchange". Clicking on that opens a menu with "Interpersonal Skills Meta" as one of the choices. 2: Near the right end of the top bar is the text "help" with a down triangle. Clicking that will open a menu with "Meta" as one of the options. Either way will take you to the home page of Interpersonal Skills Meta.

Comment: Oh, kool – I did good, then, to point it out, yeah?  As a followup, was Meta the correct place to ask it, or should I have taken it to the Help Center?

Comment: @WeaselADAPT SE Meta is the perfect place for it, here we ask questions about the main interpersonal skills website and can gain a general consensus on several topics. You can discuss things freely here (within reason), have a browse you'll get the feel for it quickly enough, The help center on the other hand is somewhat like a tutorial for both the meta and its parent, you go there to understand the framework and ins and outs of how you should behave, ask and answer questions. All stackexchange websites have one, it's always a good place to start to get a grasp of the website overall.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Technically this problem affects all sites on the Stack Exchange network (more of them than I can count) and should have been raised on the, so-called "[main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)" or sometimes "Mother Meta". The "help center" is a collection of pages with information, and no method for making "responses".

Comment: Usually referred to as "MSE".

Comment: Great.  Thank you.  I'm getting it!  I just ran through the Help Center and found unhelpful that would have been.  I guess I'll go post my other quandaries.  See you soon!

Answer (score 6):

There is one. It's right here:

[image: Meta link in footer]

That being said, calling it "meta" and then having the link say "Feedback" is... suboptimal.

It is intentional, based on a few MSE questions:

[What do they mean by feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182944/284336)
[Provide link to meta for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186731/284336)

Comment: _Suboptimal_ is a good way to be nice. I never even guessed that "Feedback" went to the site's meta. Maybe SE needs to pay more attention to [ux.se]

Comment: They have apparently hired a UX expert... we shall see.

Comment: Maybe they need a '`Meta`' link in the footer to collect user feedback. XD

Comment: They need a Meta link in the footer (or change the like I quoted in the OP to indicate you can reach Meta by clicking "Feedback" in the footer), AND they need a UX link in the footer.

Comment: @WitanapDanu It's worth noting that the link has said "feedback" since long before the new footer.

Comment: That would be why I never used it. Haven't been on SE long enough to think I had valuable feedback. Just shows how long the obtuse can survive in obscurity.

Comment: I access StackExchange sites from an android mobile phone (browser not the SE app) and the mobile page version clearly links to 'meta' in the footer; however I couldn't find 'meta' in the desktop page version and only now learned that 'feedback' means 'meta'! This is really a matter for Meta.SE but seriously they need to change 'feedback' to 'meta'.